# how can I hook into a stream of 802.15.4 frames?

Tags: java, c++, c, network-programming

Using a [packet sniffer](http://www.ti.com/tool/packet-sniffer) I am able to detect and successfully read a "hello word" payload within an [802.15.4 frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.15.4).

It's great can see the frames in the sniffer, but now I'm at the point where I would like to parse the payload out and do useful things with it.

I was wondering if the community could point me to sample C/C++/Java (or even labview, doesn't matter) code that uses hardware (like an [xbee](http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/zigbee-rf-modules/point-multipoint-rfmodules/xbee-series1-module#overview)) and can successfully parse out the payload in order to do useful operations.

Is is possible to use the [packet sniffer](http://www.ti.com/tool/packet-sniffer) I already have for this purpose?

I would greatly appreciate all / any advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I have written a much better tool that does exactly this: https://github.com/andrewdodd/pyCCSniffer

If you are still interested there are a few tools that can help you receive the sniffed packets in a more friendly environment.

I "wrote" one such tool by combining 2 others that were available on GitHub.

See here for more info https://github.com/andrewdodd/ccsniffpiper.

NB: You have to be careful which version of firmware you have loaded on the sniffer, as TI change the format of the bytestream from time to time.

Comment: I'm playing with those tools now; nice work. Dealing with the separate Cebal / libusb-win32 drivers (for TI tool / your tool) is kind of a pain. I'm considering looking into what it would take to make your tools work on Windows with the original Cebal driver.  (Perhaps faking a PyUSB backend).

Also, I didn't find any way on GitHub to communicate with you. Is that intentional, or would you mind sharing contact info? My email address is Jonathon.Reinhart@gmail.com.